# How to just after adding point, save results and come back to previous active layer in PyGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, point

I'm trying to build plugin which allow user to add point and just after adding point saves results and come back to previous active layer. I don't care about point table inputs what i need is only to allow user to manually click and add only one point.

For same reason i can detect when feature is added but cannot use it to save changes and change active layer.

That's code i written so far:

```
self.dockwidget.Add_point.clicked.connect(self.addPoint)


def addPoint(self):

    global count 

    count = 0


    point = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Point_feature')[0]
    qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(point)

    # get the current layer and print out the feature count
    point_layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    print point_layer.featureCount()

    # set the layer for editing       
    point_layer.startEditing()
    print "editing layer"



    # toggle the add feature button
    qgis.utils.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()

    ## disable feature popups
    point_layer.editFormConfig().setSuppress(1)

    #wait for mousedown
    self.iface.activeLayer().featureAdded.connect(self.logFeatureAdded)

    if count > 0:

       #save edits
        self.iface.activeLayer().commitChanges()

        #switch back to previous layer, that's test code i would like to change active layer to previous one if possible
        previousLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('previouse')[0]
        qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(previousLayer)

def logFeatureAdded(self, count): 
    global count
    count = 1
    print count  #is printing count value but i cannot use it in addPoint def.
```

Can you help me? I am using QGIS 2.16.